# Can not play .m4a file in safari that is recorded in iOS application

Tags: avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession, m4a

I am having application in which i need to record audio and than upload it on the server and mail the link of the file to the user.

Now when I try to open the mail in mac or windows it works fine and i can hear the audio. But when i try to open the link in iPhone or iPad it won't play in it.

While i had a demo application made for the project and when i try the same thing, it worked.

Please help me out.

Thank you in advance.

```
    NSArray *dirPaths;
    NSString *docsDir;

    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];


    if ([txt_RecordingName.text isEqualToString:@"Untitled"])
    {
        strFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Recording %d.m4a",[appDelegate.db getMaxId]];
        soundFilePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:strFileName];
    }
    else
    {
        strFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.m4a",txt_RecordingName.text];
        soundFilePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:strFileName];
    }
    NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC], AVFormatIDKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:16000.0], AVSampleRateKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                    nil];

    newURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
    audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
                     initWithURL:newURL
                     settings:recordSettings
                     error:nil];
    audioRecorder.delegate = self;
    [audioRecorder prepareToRecord];

    if (!audioRecorder.recording)
    {
        AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];
        [session setActive:YES error:nil];
        [audioRecorder record];
        counter = 0;
        [btnPauseRecord setEnabled:TRUE];
    }
    recordingTime = -1;
    [self showRecordingTime];
    [lbl_Recording setHidden:NO];
    [lbl_PressToStop setText:@"Press to pause"];
    [lbl_PressToStop setHidden:NO];
    [lbl_ListenToRecording setHidden:YES];
    [lbl_RecordingAgain setHidden:YES];
    [btn_ListenToRecording setHidden:YES];
    [btn_RecordAgain setHidden:YES];
    txt_RecordingName.text = strFileName;
}
else
{
    [audioRecorder stop];
    audioRecorder = nil;
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setActive:NO error:nil];

    isRecording = FALSE;

    [btnPauseRecord setEnabled:FALSE];
    [txt_RecordingName setEnabled:TRUE];
    isPaused = TRUE;
    [lbl_Recording setHidden:YES];
    [lbl_Save setHidden:NO];
    [btn_Save setHidden:NO];
    [lbl_ListenToRecording setHidden:NO];
    lbl_ListenToRecording.text = @"Listen to Recording";
    [lbl_RecordingAgain setHidden:NO];
    [btn_ListenToRecording setHidden:NO];
    [btn_RecordAgain setHidden:NO];
    lbl_PressToStop.text = @"Press to resume";
    [lblPauseRecord setHidden:YES];
    [btnPauseRecord setHidden:YES];
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors when opening the file for playing? Or is just no sound playing?